# What are the correct ways to declare constants in angular something similar to .constant in angular js?

Tags: angular, constants

I have a bunch of status code and lots of User messages which I want to put in a separate file and use it across my angular application.
I did go through a few stack overflow questions and their replies but none of them are helpful to me.

basically, I want to put all the user messages and status codes in one file something like .constant in angular js (1x) version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export a `const` form a file and then import it whereever you want:

```
export const codes = {
  '404': 'NOT FOUND',
  ...
};
```

Then import it in other files:

```
import { codes } from './path-to-the-above-file';
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/exported-const-from-other-file?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.